# Update ProgressBar with appropriate value

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

Not strong in math so here is my problem:

I am using a progress bar to show progress of work performed in background:

Snippet of my code:

```
            int i = 0;
            int totalFriends = 0;

            foreach (dynamic friend in facebookFriends)
            {
                totalFriends++;
            }

            foreach (dynamic friend in facebookFriends)
            {
                i++;

                var friend = new FacebookFriend
                {
                    FbId = friend["uid"].ToString()
                };

                AccountFacebookFriendRepository.SaveOrUpdate(accountFriend);
            }
```

Now the application does much more than that and here I am only performing a small chunk of work:
So for example before I reached this section the progress bar had value of 7 and after performing the work it has to reach to 20 and I want to update it while doing the work with appropriate values from 7 to 20:

My take on this is the following:

```
var intiProgressbarValue = 7;
var finalProgressbarvalue = 20;

foreach (dynamic friend in facebookFriends)
{
    i++;
    var friend = new FacebookFriend
                     {
                         FbId = friend["uid"].ToString()
                     };
    AccountFacebookFriendRepository.SaveOrUpdate(accountFriend);
    var calculatedValue = CalculatedValue(initProgressbarValue, finalProgressBarValue,totalFriends, i);
    UpdateProgressBar( calculatedValue);
}
//note that totalFriends can be any number lets say from 0 to 5000
private int CalculatedValue(int initVal, int finalVal, int totalFriends, int currentFriend)
{
    int progressBarVal = 0;
    //** 
       Perform logic so it will return a progress value that is bigger that 7 and smaller that 20 depending on the number of friends and currently updated friend
    **//
    progressBarVal  = 8;//this would be the result of calculation, a value from 8 to 20
    return progressBarVal;
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated:

Comment: This isn't relevant to the answer - are you sure you're using dynamic correctly?

Comment: Yes dynamic works fine, I have all the values I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
private int CalculatedValue(int initVal, int finalVal, int totalFriends, int currentFriend)
{
    initVal++;
    var diff = finalVal - initVal; // 20-8 = 12
    return (diff*(currentFriend+1))/totalFriends + initVal;
}
```

This assumes that `currentFriend` changes from 0 to totalFriends-1, inclusive. For example, if `currentFriend = 99` and `totalFriends = 300`, the answer this function returns is 12, one third through the range of 8..20 (inclusive).

Comment: This gives an off-by-one error according to the original problem, because `currentFriend` starts at 1, not 0.  Also, if `currentFriend` started at 0 as you suggest, the first value _should_ be `initVal`, but this function returns `initVal+1`.

Comment: @AdamLiss It is not clear that the current friend starts at 1. I assume that the range is the same as of an index in a C# array, and I mentioned it in the answer. I also added 1 to the answer in response to the comment in the OP's code: "this would be the result of calculation, a value from 8 to 20".

Comment: The first snippet sets `i` to 0, then increments it at the top of the `foreach` loop.  That implies that `i` is 1 the first time `CalculatedValue` is called.

Comment: @AdamLiss The OP is not using `i` anywhere in the loop, so I would be really suspicious about implying that the `currentFriend` starts at one. Anyway, it's a trivial issue to correct, because that `1` is right there in the formula.

Comment: both answers are correct, setting this as accepted answer just for full implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the formula

```
progressBarVal = initVal + (finalVal - initVal) * (currentFriend/totalFriends);
```

To check the math, calculate `progressBarVal` when `currentFriend` is 0:

```
initVal + (finalVal - initVal) * 0 = initVal
```

and when `currentFriend` is `totalFriends`:

```
initVal + (finalVal - initVal) * 1 = finalVal
```